# Ubuntu 23.04 Messed up PPA repositories

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, add-apt-repository, 23.04

Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 23. After the upgrade, I noticed that the default python3 was also upgraded to python3.11. I tried to install an older version of python through apt, but I kept getting

```
E: Package 'python3.10' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to solve it by changing the name of the PPA repositories to the new version in the `sources.list` file

```
❯ sudo sed -i ‘s/jammy/lunar/g’ /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After the above command all the repos were unchecked from the "Software & Updates" app/settings.

[Software & Updates -> Other Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsa3z.png)

If I manually enable the deadsnake one (the one that should have python packaged), I'll get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/nightly/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I feel like I messed this up quite bad.. Could anyone help me figure it out?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I ended up build ing python3.8 from source. Looks like the repository that I used previously doesn't support the new Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: Install anaconda and set up a virtual environment for python3.10 https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python

Comment: Changing the python interpreter can be a system killer. You may need to reinstall the OS.  Don't change the python interpreter on your system. Use virtual environments instead.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi yea, the project I'm working on requires a separate virtualenv for pip

Comment: @Nmath right, though the python interpreter got during the system upgrade to ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, I think it does. Yesterday I was able to build python3.8 from source. I had the assumption that the PPA repositories always support the new releases, but it's totally up on the maintainers.